# RGBA code for red color

Tags: rgba

I'm looking for RGBA code for red color with opacity: Can someone tell me how can i find about it?(or where i can learn more about RGBA colors? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA

Answer (score 30):

```
rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)
```

The range for red, green and blue is 0-255.
The high the number, the more presence the color shows.

The range for alpha is 0.0-1.0.
The higher the number, the higher the opacity.

Fully opaque red would be `rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)`

Comment: +1 Sometimes alpha is also specified as an integral in the range `[0, 255]` for a 32-bit color with 8-bit channels (including alpha); for a 1-bit alpha channel it would be `0 -or- 1`, etc. However, thinking of opacity as decimal number in `[0.0, 1.0]` is nice [and *the* way to represent alpha in some encodings] and makes a bunch of math "just work".